# How can I fix the tree chart that goes off page in LaTeX

Tags: qtree

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}  
\paragraph{Question 6}
\Tree[.Ad [.\text{Sees Ad} 
                   [.\text{Doesn't Try} ][.\text{Tries} 
                        [.\text{Doesn't Become Regular} ] [.\text{Becomes Regular} ]
                                                                                                               ]][.\text{Doesn't See Ad} 
                                                                    [.\text{Doesn't Try} ][.\text{Tries}
                                                                                    [.\text{Doesn't Become Regular} ][.\text{Becomes Regular} ] ]]
]
\end{document}
```

Hi, when I try to draw this tree chart it goes off page. How can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome! I'd suggest you switch to `forest` since with `forest` it is much easier to avoid unnecessary space (which ironically saves trees. ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{forest}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Question 6}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
for tree={align=center}
 [Ad
  [Sees Ad
   [Doesn't Try]
   [Tries
    [Doesn't\\ Become\\ Regular]
    [Becomes\\ Regular]
   ]
  ]
  [Doesn't See Ad
   [Doesn't Try]
   [Tries
    [Doesn't\\ Become\\ Regular]
    [Becomes\\ Regular]
   ]
  ]
 ]   
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]